# Shortest way of checking if Double is "NaN"

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point

When calling `Double.IsNaN()` with `Double.PositiveInfinity` as argument, the result is false. This is against my intuition since infinity is not a number. Apparently "NaN" only exists in terms of a constant in .NET, is this described by the IEEE standard or is it a custom implementation detail? Is there a shorter way to check if a `Double` is "NaN" than:

```
(Double.IsNaN(d) || Double.IsPositiveInfinity(d) || Double.IsNegativeInfinity(d))
```

or

```
(Double.IsNaN(d) || Double.IsInfinity(d))
```

Comment: Wouldn't expect this to get any shorter unless you just create your own custom wrapper function.

Comment: NaN is described in the IEEE standard yes (in fact it's slightly more elaborate, with quite NaNs and signaling NaNs). It's a possible value for a floating point number, not a category "anything but plain old numbers".

Comment: I have rarely encountered situations in which NaN and the infinities should be treated the same way. Many computations work correctly, and get meaningful results, with infinities in the data. Before making extensive use of an IsNanOrInfinity function, look carefully at whether it really makes sense for your computation.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan - Fortunately I'm not doing any floating-point computations. I'm validating two doubles which represent a range between `Double.MinValue` and `Double.MaxValue`. As far as I know, it doesn't make sense for either of them to be NaN.

Comment: Can you accept Roman Marusyk's answer as the correct one? The accepted answer is outdated with respect to .net 5 onwards.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

As MSDN says, [NaN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan(v=vs.110).aspx) means that result is undefined. With infinities result is defined:

> A method or operator returns NaN when the result of an operation is
>   undefined. For example, the result of dividing zero by zero is NaN, as
>   the following example shows. (But note that dividing a non-zero number
>   by zero returns either PositiveInfinity or NegativeInfinity, depending
>   on the sign of the divisor.)

So, it's not good idea to tread infinities as NaN. You can write extension method to check if value is not NaN or infinity:

```
// Or IsNanOrInfinity
public static bool HasValue(this double value)
{
    return !Double.IsNaN(value) && !Double.IsInfinity(value);
}
```

Comment: Using an extension method is pretty neat. I guess it can't get better than this.

Comment: `HasValue` would be misleading I guess, since infinity **is** a value.

Comment: @Mario agree, that's why another suggested name is `IsNanOrInfinity`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: `IsFinite` is a common convention.

Answer (score 15):

You no longer need an extension from SergeyBerezovskiy answer.

`double` has `IsFinite()` method to check if a double is a finite number (is not `NaN` or `Infinity`):

```
double.IsFinite(d)
```

See source code in [.Net Framework](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Standard/DoubleUtil.cs,116) and [.Net Core](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Double.cs,74)

Comment: Should be noted that this is only available from .Net Standard 2.1, for people that are stuck with 2.0 (like Unity devs), this function is still unavailable almost 2 years after this answer.

Answer (score 4):

There are three special values in the `Double` type, which is based on [IEEE standard 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).  One is Positive Infinity, another is Negative Infinity, and the last is Not-a-Number (NaN).  All that the `Double.IsNaN` method does is check to see if the value in the variable is this special NaN value.

Answer (score 4):

If you'd like the value of `double` to always be a number, you could use this `FiniteOrDefault` extension. It is of course inspired by [Sergey Berezovskiy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24697553/8058709).

```
public static bool HasValue(this double value)
{
    return !double.IsNaN(value) && !double.IsInfinity(value);
}

/// <summary>
/// Returns zero when double is NaN or Infinte
/// </summary>
public static double FiniteOrDefault(this double value)
{
    return value.HasValue() ? value : default;
}
```

With that, code like the following can be much more readable:

```
Rect dimensions = new Rect
{
    X = Canvas.GetLeft(Control).FiniteOrDefault(),
    Y = Canvas.GetTop(Control).FiniteOrDefault(),
    Width = Control.ActualWidth.FiniteOrDefault(),
    Height = Control.ActualHeight.FiniteOrDefault()
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end, all you are looking at is the bit value of the double. The IEEE standard 754, used by double, states:

- Positive Infinity has all Exponent bits set, all Significand bits not set, and Sign bit not set.
- Negative Infinity has all Exponent bits set, all Significand bits not set, and Sign bit set.
- Nan has all Exponent bits set and at least one Significand bit set. Sign bit can be set or not set. In C#, the constant double.NaN has the Sign bit and most significant Significand bit set.

Therefore, if you don't want to use built-in functions, you can simply check if all Exponent bits are set yourself. You can do this in one of two ways, use unsafe code to extract long value of double or use `BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits`, then check Exponent bits.

```
public unsafe static bool IsNaNorInfinity(double d)
{
    return (*(long*)(&d) & 0x7FF0000000000000L) == 0x7FF0000000000000L;
}
```

```
public static bool IsNaNorInfinity(double d)
{
    return (BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(d) & 0x7FF0000000000000L) == 0x7FF0000000000000L;
}
```