# How to check if a variable is non-double for this particular case?

Tags: c#

I have simple GUI a program where the real time plot(using `WinForms` chart) crashes due to non-double values like infinity or `NaN`.
So I want to filter values such as infinity,`NaN` or `ect`. And only plot valid double values. It can also be any other non-double type.

I try the following:

```
if(!double.IsInfinity(value)){

chart1.Series["mySerie"].Points.AddY(value);

}
```

But the above only checks if the value is not infinity not other non-double possibilities.
In my case Double. `TryParse` also would not work because it is used to check whether text is a double.

So in my case I receive data from a device normally a double. But sometimes it outputs non-double values and is there a quick fix for it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shortest way of checking if Double is "NaN"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697495/shortest-way-of-checking-if-double-is-nan) and [How to check if the value of string variable is double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48228494/how-to-check-if-the-value-of-string-variable-is-double)

Comment: Some hack would be to just check `value > MIN_ACCEPTABLE && value < MAX_ACCEPTABLE`, with the boundaries chosen as the borderline meaningful values for your plot (depends on application). E.g. between 0 and 1e6

Comment: What are "non-double" values? As far as I (and IEEE 754) am concerned, infinities and NaNs are all valid `double` values.

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov I think that would inherently filter any non-double values correct?

Comment: Also perhaps you can use [double.MinValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.double.minvalue) and MaxValue. but using axis min and max should be better if it is the chart that refuses data.

Comment: @Sweeper Im trying to fix this issue: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ca55daf4-182e-4cab-8e04-ebf7fd601a8f/systeminvalidoperationexception-axis-object-8211-auto-interval-error-due-to-invalid-point?forum=MSWinWebChart

Comment: What about creating an extension method that simply checks whether your value is valid by calling ```Double.IsNaN``` and ```Double.IsInfinity```?

Answer (score 0):

Double has a few static methods that could help you do this. If you want to check the different states individually you can use the following methods:

```
Double.IsInfinite(value); //returns true if the value is infinite
Double.IsNaN(value); //returns true if the value is NaN
```

As you want to disregard other non-double values, I would suggest using one of the following:

```
Double.IsNormal(value); //returns true if the value is normal
Double.IsSubnormal(value); //returns true if the value is subnormal
Double.IsFinite(value) //returns true if the value is zero, normal, or subnormal
```

Any of these will help filter your input, so use the one that matches the input that you need. `IsFinite` is the only one of the 3 I believe that will return true if the value is 0

The entire set of methods for the Double type can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score -1):

To illustrate my comment with a range of acceptable values:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static bool Check(double x) {
        double min = -1e6, max = 1e6;
        return x > min && x < max;  
    }
        
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"NaN {Check(double.NaN)}");               // False
        Console.WriteLine($"-inf {Check(double.NegativeInfinity)}"); // False
        Console.WriteLine($"-1e7 {Check(-1e7)}");                    // False
        Console.WriteLine($"0 {Check(0)}");                          // True
        Console.WriteLine($"1e7 {Check(1e7)}");                      // False
        Console.WriteLine($"+inf {Check(double.PositiveInfinity)}"); // False
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
    if(Double.IsNaN(value)||Double.IsInfinity(value) ){
        //do nothing
    }else{
        chart1.Series["mySerie"].Points.AddY(value);
    }
```