# c# "not a number" in console

Tags: c#, math, console

when I try to get the value of x1 and x2, the console tells me that x1 is not a number and x2 is ?

here is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    long a, b, c;
    double x1, x2, D;
    Console.WriteLine("Write the numbers a, b, c: ");
    string[] names = Console.ReadLine().Split(" ");
    a = long.Parse(names[0]);
    b = long.Parse(names[1]);
    c = long.Parse(names[2]);
    try
    {

        D = Math.Pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c;
        if (D > 0)
        {
            x1 = (-b + Math.Sqrt(D)) / (2.0 * a);
            x2 = (-b - Math.Sqrt(D)) / (2.0 * a);
            Console.WriteLine($"x1 = {x1}, x2 = {x2}");
        }
        if (D == 0)
        {
            x1 = (-b) / (2 * a);
            if (a != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"x1 = x2 = {x1}");
            }
            if (a == 0) { Console.WriteLine($"x = {x1}"); }
        }
        if (D < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("there are no roots");
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        if (a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("x - any number");
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("there are no solutions");
        }
    }
}
```

I changed the data type of x1 and x2, which led to the fact that the cat began to write to me "there are no solutions" (on catch line)
i used numbers 0 1 0 and 0 1 2

Comment: What are your inputs?

Comment: what is the input you used

Comment: i used numbers 0 1 0 and 0 1 2

Comment: NaN means that you have tried to execute an illegal operation like evaluating the square root of a negative number or a division with zero. Use your debugger to check the values of your numbers.

Comment: When working with a formula like the quadratic formula, consider using only `double` values (integer math can be surprising). Also realize when you are working with floating point values, equality checks should _usually_ be "are really close to equal" checks and not "are equal" checks. For an example of the first problem, look at `x1 = (-b) / (2 * a);`. What is `x1` if `b` is 5 and `a` is 1

Comment: By the way, `NaN` (not a number) is not what you get from dividing by zero. A div by zero results in positive or negative infinity (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697495/shortest-way-of-checking-if-double-is-nan). You get `NaN` when you take the square root of a negative number or the logarithm of zero (or other undefined operations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your data 0 1 0 you get D = 1. Therefore you enter the branch with the condition D > 0. Trying to evaluate x1 and x2 you are dividing by your variable a which is zero. The result is NaN.
With your data set 0 1 2 it's quite the same: D = 1, a = 0 resulting in NaNs for x1 an x2.

Answer (score 0):

In math we cannot divide by 0 never, you will need to put a logic to handle that scenario when a is equals to 0